# Evaluate JavaScript within a HTML with Java

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to get the generated html output from a javascript within a given html string in java.

First, i just don't know, how to set the full html and javascript in code. all i've seen is, that i can give some small javascript to java, invoke some parameters and get some output.
Is there a way to set a html-string as context??

The example (taken from another thread):

```
<html>
    <head><title> test </title>

    <body></body>
    <div>Welcome</div>
    <style type="text/css">
        .title{
            color:red
        }
    </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            for (i=0;i < 5;i++){
                document.writeln("<div class='title'>" + i + "</div>");
            }
    </script>
</html>
```

What i want to do is, to pass this html code into javascript context and call the function (actually there is no function, but i know how to call javascripts functions)

then, Rendering in a browser will give you this html back:

```
<html>
    <head><title> test </title>

    <body></body>
    <div>Welcome</div>
    <style type="text/css">
        .title{
            color:red
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i=0;
        for (i=0;i < 5;i++){
            document.writeln("<div class='title'>" + i + "</div>");
        }
    </script>
    <div class="title">0</div>
    <div class="title">1</div>
    <div class="title">2</div>
    <div class="title">3</div>
    <div class="title">4</div>
</html>
```

So, the basic output on the javascripting mangere is simple:

```
Welcome
0
1
2
3
4
```

I don't want to render any of these elements, i am simply interested in getting the html output.
I'm not sure how to perform this task.

I want to keep it simple, no frameworks at all, just a simple mechanic to pass html-code and javafunctions into the javascriptengine, evaluate it and get the html back, just like the browsers getting more html-code back (usually).
there's no rendering intended.

Comment: Why do you put your html code outside of the <body>?

Comment: this is just an quick html example i made. the problem won't be the <body> at all. keep focus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the new Nashorn javascript engine in Java 8?

I havent actually used it yet, so I am not sure if you can just pass it an html string or if you will need to separate the JS and HTML, but worth taking a look.

Theres a basic tutorial here:
http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/

If not, there is always PhantomJS that you can use to execute Javascript. There are some examples here: 
http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html

Looks like there are some useful functions like page loading and code evaluating that you may be able to use.